# Check if Data was entered by the User or by a macro [VBA]

Tags: vba, excel, validation

In my VBA-Project I have different Buttons (Ribbon Bar with Custom UI Editor) that start Subs, which enter data into the Cells. I want to prevent the users from entering data on their own to the cells as this might destroy the routines. Is there a way to validate whether the data has been entered manually or automatically? I thought about a control sheet where I would put a variable to 1 if I am in a function and check for this variable in the worksheet_change sub. Anyhow I think this might be a risky way as a Sub can always crash and then the value is still at 1 and no values can be entered anymore.

Comment: Lock the sheet with [`UserInterfaceOnly` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel) set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you simply lock the sheet from user input with the `Protect` function.

You have to use the `UserInterfaceOnly` property of this function to achieve what you're trying to do.

```
Sheets(“sheetname”).Protect Password:="Secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

This will protect your sheet from user input and let VBA change values in the sheet.

**EDIT - Disable alerts**

You asked in the comments if it's possible to disable alerts when the user select these cells. The following code should do the trick.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Working as intended. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have got another question now. If the User Double Clicks on the Field he gets a notification that it is read only. Can I stop this dialog? I have tried: Application.DisplayAlerts = False but this does not do anything...

Comment: @C.Henke I edited my answer please read the **Edit** part, this should do what you were trying to.